# How to restrict Release Deployments during office hours in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps we only want that Release Pipelines are allowed to being manually triggered for deployments by engineers outside business hours, anything within business hours needs to be rejected unless there is a critical issue.

Is there a way to restrict deployments for Classic Release Pipeline deployments in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

This is supported out of the box with YAML pipelines and environments. Environments support adding [checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass) that run before a deployment can run there, one of which is [business hours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#business-hours).

There is nothing equivalent for classic release pipelines.

Comment: Thank you! What kind of custom solution would you suggest for the Classic Release Pipelines?

Comment: The business hours check is not suitable for *outside* business hours. You cannot define a time range from 22h until 4h next morning.

Answer (score 0):

For classic release one might try using [gates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-using-approvals?view=azure-devops) to reject releases that are outside allowed time ranges. The gating logic itself implemented in an Azure function or external service.